# How to setup a build with .bitrise.yml with minimal intervention from the web-ui side?

Tags: travis-ci, bitrise

I like the way I just copy some snippet of code to a `.travis.yml` file, and then enable the repository on travis-ci.org and everything is ready to go with almost no configuration from the web-ui side.

Also, it has the benefit that if someone wants to improve the .yml file they just make a pull request on GitHub.com and that's it.

So, I wonder if there is a way to do what I've described with Bitrise.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use a config from the repository.

Please see the DevCenter: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/tips-and-tricks/use-bitrise-yml-from-repository/

as well as this related blog post might help (probably a better, practical getting-started): https://blog.bitrise.io/run-a-workflow-from-your-repository

In short: you just define a "wrapper" config on bitrise.io which does nothing else other than getting the source code (usually: 1) activate an SSH key then 2) do a Git Clone) and then running `bitrise run X` which runs your config from the repository, the same way you'd run `bitrise run` locally on your Mac/Linux.

If you'd have any questions just let us know! :)

Comment: I think I'll have to do the wrapper config approach, and optionaly put some comments in the repo's .yml file with what's needed in order to load the build settings from the wrapper. Or maybe include the wrapper in the repo too, although that is just to copy-paste the wrapper to the workflow editor. Not an ideal situation for me, but maybe they will add a default wrapper or some other options in the future.

Comment: @rraallvv we do have plans to auto-detect during registration if the repository includes a bitrise.yml and auto-setup this wrapper. It's on our roadmap but no ETA yet. If you're interested you can find the related feature request at https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/allow-bitrise-yml-to-be-pulled-from-project-source-code/154